# Subdivided cube to football instead of sphere

Tags: subdivision-surface

I get a football shape when using Subdivide Smooth on a freshly created cube.Am I doing something wrong? or have I found a bug?

Before:

[image]

---

After:

[image]

Comment: Footballs are round or pointy, depending on which country you live in and which language you speak. Please include some screenshots so we can see what you're talking about.

Comment: please read: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/subsurf.html?highlight=modifiers

Comment: How do I add a screenshot?

Comment: Trying to follow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FKkUOMB6Zsc&list=PLXMRarQYThdaFETVoc-ly8KZ4Os5qEsk6&index=5 and not getting the 1st sphere from cube he gets; I get the pointy football

Comment: When I increase the cuts, I get a football with a lot of cuts.

Comment: When the tutor uses Subdivide smooth on a freshly created cube, he gets a sphere that he then increases the cuts on to 2. I get an American-style footbaal that just becomes a smoother football when I increase cuts, & turns into a Xmas-star when I increase Smoothness

Comment: Fractal is set to 0

Comment: I raise it by z-axis, out of the rectangular box it,s created in, because origin is centered there, then immediately subdivide.

Comment: @KennyleeBeeks instead of adding lots of comments use the [edit] link to modify the text of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png)

Comment: Go into Object Mode, press ***Ctrl  A***, and select ***Rotation & Scale***.  Then go back into your object and try to subdivide the Cube.

Comment: @cegaton - It's my fault, I was asking questions

Comment: The reason you had to do that is because you scaled it previously in Object Mode.  If you do all of your scaling in Edit Mode, the object scale doesn't change.  Nearly all modifying functions are influenced by object scale.